# Jira API Help C# HttpClient

Tags: c#, api, jira, dotnet-httpclient

Okay, so I'm very new to using API's in code and I've been able to use a few that were actually pretty easy. But none of them required authentication. I've been trying to use Jira's REST API service via C#'s HttpClient class. See code below:

```
public void UpdateJiraIssue(string issueValue)
        {
            string url = $@"http://jira.mySite.com/rest/api/2/issue/{issueValue}/editmeta";
            string jsonString = @"myNeatJsonData";
            var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            //Initialize Client
            HttpClient apiClient = new HttpClient();
            apiClient.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(url);
            apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            byte[] cred = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:password");
            apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(cred));
            apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            async Task RunJiraAPI()
            {

                using (HttpResponseMessage resp = await apiClient.PostAsync("editmeta", content))
                {
                    if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var jsonSring = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
            RunJiraAPI();

            return;
        }
```

The problem I run into is that I get a 401 error (Authentication). Here's what my 'resp' object contains when I run the code:

```
resp: {StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: ' ', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-AREQUESTID: 400x1314x1
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
  X-ASEN: SEN-11158344
  X-AUSERNAME: anonymous
  Cache-Control: no-store, no-transform, no-cache
  Set-Cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=B2ZY-C2JQ-1AGH-PBLW_5ccc79da5af8e6abcb9bff5250f3305af3b2877a_lout; Path=/; Secure
  WWW-Authenticate: OAuth realm="https%3A%2F%2Fjira.mySite.com"
  X-Powered-By: ARR/3.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Date: Wed, 15 Jan 2020 13:40:22 GMT
  Content-Length: 109
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
}}

Request Message: {Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://jira.rhlan.com/rest/api/2/issue/RHD-1116/editmeta', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Authorization: Basic cWE6aGVjc29mdDEyMw==
  Accept: application/json
  Content-Type: Application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 70
}}

Status Code: Unauthorized
```

I need to work on my json string a bit to get it working right (which is why I didn't include what it actually contains), but once I get passed the authentication error, I'll probably actually change things to do a get Jira issue via the API so I can see all the json data returned that way. Then I'll edit my json string accordingly.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Hope that the response message has been cleared of any personal data, including that base64 string.

Comment: checkout the doc [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/basic-auth-for-rest-apis/). You need an api token.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in credentials assuming you have a username and an api token.

```
string credentials= string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, apitoken);
    byte[] byteCredentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials);
```

And in your apiClient you can use it like this.

```
apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteCredentials));
```

Comment: Okay. So I'll have to get a token then. I'll figure out how to get a token and see if that works for me.

Comment: Got a token. But it looks like this solution didn't work. Still getting a 401. Jira's so customizable that I wonder if its API's are even going to be reliable. But I suppose I should at least still be able to connect to an API service with creds. Who knows?

Comment: Is there a library / Nuget package I shuold install for that line of code?  `apiClient.Headers` isn't an extension for me. I only see `apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders`.

Comment: Sorry, I confused HttpClient with WebClient (please ignore). I would try a get request to make sure the issue is not username/password.  It could be permission related on JIRA side.

Answer (score 0):

You need a username and api-token. Your api-token should be your login password.